# Pandas read data by rows

Tags: python, pandas

Normally the data is presented with columns being the variables, but if for example I had in a .txt file something like

```
Data1,1,2,3,4,5
Data2,3,1,4
```

can I use pandas in such a way that it constructs the data frame as what I would obtain from

```
d = {"Data1":[1,2,3,4,5], "Data2": [3,1,4,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Edit :
Originally I wanted tha data sets to be different in size but pandas won't allow it throwing a `ValueError`

Comment: `d = {"Data1":[[1,2,3,4,5]], "Data2": [[3,1,4]]}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file in, transpose the dataframe, munge a little... et voilà.

Setup for faking your file:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> file = StringIO('''Data1,1,2,3,4,5
...:Data2,3,1,4''')
```

Create the dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None).T
>>> df = df.rename(columns=df.loc[0]).drop(0, axis=0)
>>> 
>>> df
>>> 
  Data1 Data2
1     1     3
2     2     1
3     3     4
4     4   NaN
5     5   NaN
```

However, this is done a little more elegantly in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53341919/3620003) answer by Peter Leimbigler!

As ALollz has pointed out, these solutions only work when there is no row in your file with more fields than the first row.

Here's my attempt at a more generally applicable solution:

```
>>> file = StringIO('''Data1,3,1,4
...:Data2,1,2,3,4,5
...:Data3,7,8''')
>>> df = pd.concat([pd.Series(line.split(',')) for line in file], axis=1)
>>> df.rename(columns=df.loc[0]).drop(0, axis=0).astype(float)
>>> 
   Data1  Data2  Data3
1    3.0    1.0    7.0
2    1.0    2.0    8.0
3    4.0    3.0    NaN
4    NaN    4.0    NaN
5    NaN    5.0    NaN
```

Comment: But this only works because the first row *happens* to have the most data. Swap the rows and it fails, because it can't tokenize properly.

Comment: @ALollz true, I tried my hand at finding a more general solution that does not copy yours ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.read_csv('example_data.txt', header=None, index_col=0).T
df
0  Data1  Data2
1    1.0    3.0
2    2.0    1.0
3    3.0    4.0
4    4.0    NaN
5    5.0    NaN
```

Comment: Ah, even better! edit: @Alex I think the answer tick should go here!

Comment: @timgeb, I see we came up with very similar answers at the exact same time :)

Answer (score 2):

In the case that your first row isn't the longest you can read in the entire line and then split it with pandas.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\n', header=None)
df[0].str.split(',', expand=True).set_index(0).rename_axis(None,0).T

  Data1 Data2 Data3
1     1     3     1
2     2     1     2
3     3     4     3
4     4  None     4
5     5  None     5
6  None  None     6
7  None  None     7
8  None  None     8
9  None  None     9
```

#### Sample Data: `test.csv`:

```
Data1,1,2,3,4,5
Data2,3,1,4
Data3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: Honest question - is that really the best way to import CSV data (using pandas) where the first row isn't the longest?

Comment: @Evan I don't know. The parser expects to never see any rows with more fields than the first non-header row, so I think the only safe way to do that is to read everything into a single field with pandas. I'm lost for a different wayt to accomplish that. There are likely smarter ways to do this with a .csv reader, but those two lines are conceptually simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `data_dict = {line.split(',')[0]:{line.split(',')[1:] for line in lines}` where `lines` is created by reading in the data. Then apply whatever rule you want to get `[3,1,4,1,2]` instead of `[3,1,4]` (you don't say what rule you want). Then do `pd.DataFrame(data_dict)`.